# Stack n-dimensional array in a n+1-dimensional array with a sliding window

Tags: python, numpy

Is there some kind of "strided stacking" function in numpy to speed up this for loop:

```
>>> def stack(vals, moving_window):
...     steps = len(vals) - moving_window + 1
...     es = [vals[i:i+moving_window] for i in range(steps)]
...     return np.array(es)
...
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> stack(a, 3)
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [5, 6, 7]])
```

I've looked at [stack](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html), vstack, hstack, block, concatenate, etc. but wasn't able to find anything.

Comment: `from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as swv ; swv(a, 3)`